# Keeping track of changes I make by copying project folders

Tags: c#, version-control

I'm a beginner so if there is a terminology for what I'm doing I don't know how to search for it. So forgive me if this has been asked before. So here is what I do. Before I make any major code changes, I make a copy of the projects folder and call it "project v6" for example. Then if I really mess things up and cant find a way to undo it, I just go back to the previous folder. This has been working well enough for me but sometimes I forget to do this and have to take 2 steps back. Is there an easier way to do this than the way I am now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many source control tools, which keeps track of all this stuff. [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)), [subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software)), [cvs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) (used wikipedia links, which explains each with more detail. This can be done much more easily once you get used to them.

In both there is commit what you've done to a server (which may be your own machine). But you can store your code somewhere else (so you don't lose everything, in case your hard disk fails or something like that). [Google Code](http://code.google.com/) is a good example.

Git - harder to use, but very powerful (more used when there are lots of people working on the same project, and even the same file sometimes), much easier to deal with branches and stuff like that (if you don't know what that is, so you probably don't need it yet)

svn (subversion) and cvs - simpler to use, with fewer resources available. Probably enough for your needs

Comment: With subversion it can be done more easily and you don't have to get used to it.  You just have to commit your changes once in a while.  Daily is the typical suggestion.

Comment: Don't use CVS: it is seriously outdated (but still better than not using version control).

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is revision/source control software.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree you need to start using a source control system.  Even if for no other reason than to ingrain good work habits, you will be required at some point to use a source control system.

Having said, if your IDE is Visual Studio (non-express editions) you can use an addins to:

- zip the sln for you, such as [codeproject - zipstudio](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/zipstudio.aspx) 
  or
- keep a "local file history à la Eclipse" [visual local history](http://vlh2005.codeplex.com/)